# SQL issues with join function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm using MySQL / PHP to store my data.

I have a website with posts and I would like to be able to order them by tags. (The posts have multiple tags)

There are 3 tables.

**medias** (posts)

```
+----+--------+-----+
| id | title  | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | hello  | ... |
|  2 | hi     | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
```

**tags**

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | ... |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | red  | ... |
|  2 |square| ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

**medias_tags** (In order to link the medias & tags together)

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | media_id | tag_id |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |        1 |      2 |
|  3 |        2 |      2 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

So I'm using this SQL query to join the tables together and output the post with a certain tag.

```
$req_mda_list = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM medias 
JOIN medias_tags 
ON medias.id=medias_tags.media_id 
WHERE medias_tags.tag_id ='.$tag_id.' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT '.$start.','.$limit);
```

It works *however* when I make an other SQL query inside in order to get the others tags of each posts (The posts have multiple tags) it doesn't works. I tried to twist the queries but I either get no data from the query or random tags.

```
$data_mda = $req_mda_list->fetch()){

 $req_mda_tags = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM medias_tags WHERE media_id = ?');
 $req_mda_tags->execute(array($mda_id));      

 $mda_tags_list = null;

 while ($data_mda_tags = $req_mda_tags->fetch()){
    $tag_id = $data_mda_tags['tag_id'];

    $req_tag_name = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id = ?');
    $req_tag_name->execute(array($tag_id));
    $data_tag_name = $req_tag_name->fetch();

    $mda_tags_list .= $data_tag_name['name'].' ';
 }

 #Show media title

 echo $mda_tags_list;

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the posts are sorted by tags? How should they be sorted?

Comment: Did you try to add `$req_mda_tags->store_result();` after `$req_mda_tags->execute(array($mda_id));`?

Comment: @YuryFedorov They must be sorted with the post title and the tags associated

Comment: @AycanYaşıt I just tried but it didn't change anything. The other tags are not shown even tho the posts are sorted by selected tag.

Comment: is this sql server or mysql? Can you add correct dbms? Looks like it is only mysql..

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do -- sample data, desired results, and an explanation.  Non-working code doesn't always do a good job of expressing intent.

Comment: 3 questions: 1. Where is `$mda_id` set and 2. what is it set to? 3. Did you miss pasting part of the code? It looks like there should be a `while` or maybe an `if` at the beginning of the php code block.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to list the names of all of the tags associated to `medias`?.

MySQL has built-in function called [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). You can use that to get all the tag names in one query.

```
SELECT m.media_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS tag_names
FROM media_tags m
INNER JOIN tags t ON m.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY m.media_id
```

If you want to get the list of tags just per `media_id`, you can just add a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT m.media_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS tag_names
FROM media_tags m
INNER JOIN tags t ON m.tag_id = t.id
WHERE m.media_id = ?
GROUP BY m.media_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
select      m.title
           ,t.name

from                    medias_tags mt

            join        media       m

            on          m.media_id  = mt.media_id

            join        tags        t

            on          t.tag_id    = mt.tag_id

order by    m.title
           ,t.name
;
```

or this? -

```
select      m.title
           ,group_concat(t.name order by t.name)    as tags

from                    medias_tags mt

            join        media       m

            on          m.media_id  = mt.media_id

            join        tags        t

            on          t.tag_id    = mt.tag_id

group by    m.title

order by    m.title
;
```